My batch file cannot continue on when I enter the number 2
I wrote a batch script that asks for an input. The script closes whenever I type "2" and hit Enter. I checked the loop but it looks completely fine. At first I thought it was an error with some of the variables, but it wasn't. Also this script checks for admin privileges but with the permissions, it doesn't work. I could do all the commands successfully without loading it as admin privileges.
By the way, please explain it in a way so that I can understand. I am 13 years old...
This is my code:
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
color 0A
title Slimy's Account Hacking Tool
set /p pass="Enter password: "
cls
if "%pass%" NEQ "slimy" exit
:menu
echo.
echo  ***************
echo       Menu
echo  ***************
echo.
echo.
echo 1) List Users on Computer
echo 2) Create a New User
echo 3) Change a User's Password
echo 4) Delete a User Account
echo 5) Exit Slimy's Account Hacking Tool
echo.
set /p input="©️ "

if %input% EQU 1 (
    title List Users
    cls
    net user
    pause
    cls
    goto menu
)

if "%input%" EQU 2 (
    call checkadmin
    title Create a New User
    cls
    set /p user="USERNAME: "
    set /p password="PASSWORD: "
    net user %user% %password% /add
    echo New user created with credentials:
    echo %user% : %password%
    pause
    cls
    goto menu
)

if %input% EQU 3 (
    call checkadmin
    title Change a USer's Password
    cls
    set /p username="TARGET USER: "
    set /p passsword="NEW PASSWORD: "
    net user %username% %password%
    pause
    cls
    goto menu
)

if %input% EQU 4 (
    cls
    echo you have no morals and are messed up for trying to do this.
    timeout /t 3
    cls
    goto menu
)

if %input% EQU 5 Exit

:checkadmin
net session >nul
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    cls
    echo.
    echo Restart the script and run it as admin.
)


@JohnGordon Your language is not kind. New users are like little children. We have to be extraordinarily patient with their faux pas. OP thank you for providing source.

call checkadmin tries to call an external script. To call a label within the same script, you NEED the colon: call :checkadmin (other than in GOTO, which doesn't care if there is a colon or not)

In addition to the advice given above, I see another problem with your submitted code. You are both creating variables, and trying to use them within a parenthesized code block. For that reason, typing 2 or 3 will not achieve the intended net.exe commands, without changing your structure, or enabling delayed variable expansion.

Please also reconsider using a variable named username. There is already a Windows environment variable with that name.

Notice that your condition for a “2” has quotes around the variable name:
if "%input%" EQU 2 (

The comparison then becomes: does "2" equal 2. The answer is no.
Using quotes is often a good idea, but you must also put quotes around the other side:
if "%input%" EQU "2" (

Notice also that your script ends with an exit, which will terminate the cmd interpreter. If you only mean to terminate your script, you should instead use one of goto :EOF or exit /b.
